# sh: 1: rimraf: not found whenever I run npm run build within vagrant installed on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, vagrant, windows-10

I want to run a webpack project within Vagrant (installed on Windows 10) where I embedded a Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine.

I was able to install `npm 5.6.0` and `nodejs v8.9.4` very successfully.

I tried to run `npm install` to install all my dependencies. After getting these errors :

```
...
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-116-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /vagrant/src/my_project/static/node_modules/contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
...
```

I tried : `npm install --no-bin-links`, which gave me the same kind of erros above.

So I then run : `npm run build`

And now I keep getting this error :

```
sh: 1: rimraf: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! my-project@1.0.0 clean: `rimraf dist`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-project@1.0.0 clean script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-03-04T04_44_09_988Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-project@1.0.0 build: `npm run clean && webpack`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-project@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-03-04T04_44_10_048Z-debug.log
```

Here is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "author": "Edgar KAMDEM",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "acorn": "^5.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "fabric": "^1.7.22",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.12.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mxgraph": "^3.8.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-input-range": "^1.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.2.0",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.6",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.9",
    "precss": "^2.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2"
  }
}
```

Don't know what to do, I'm lost. I tried everything on Google (Github, SO etc). Nothing work.

Please help!

Comment: According to the errors, you're using `node v4.2.6` and `npm  v3.5.2`, not `8.9.4` respectively `5.6.0`.

Comment: Instead of `npm install`, try with `npm install --no-bin-links`.

Comment: @Svenskunganka sorry I edited my answer (I copied the wrong file). I also did `npm install --no-bin-links` with no success

Answer (score 23):

Just add this script to your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "rimraf": "./node_modules/rimraf/bin.js",
}
```

The current behavior is looking for globally installed rimraf (you can do it as well by executing `npm i -g rimraf`), but the line above says it should use local project's version.

Comment: how come rimraf cannot be run from local `node_modules` by default, like so many other packages can?

Comment: @mesqueeb: perhaps you have missed to configure your system first by running `npm config set ignore-scripts true`, see [Package install scripts vulnerability](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/141702881055/package-install-scripts-vulnerability) back from March 2016.

Answer (score 12):

In some rare cases, `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` will fail to create the file **bin.js** in the following location

```
C:\Users\{{user}}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\rimraf
```

So try creating the missed file first by running the following command

```
npm i -g rimraf
```

Now you can run `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` and it will install angular without any problems